# create module for python package

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, lua, centos

I have recently installed kmos, a python package using pip in my user account on my institute cluster. How to create a module for kmos and set the path to the directory such that python accesses the library. Currently, I am giving the path to the kmos binary while running the program.

Linux distro: Cent OS
Module support: Lua-based Lmod environmental modules system

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by "How to create a module for kmos". You didn't mention which terminal you are using. However it will be definitely helpful to understand the mechanism behind finding executables and python import.

If you want to execute the `kmos` command-line interface (e.g. `kmos export ...`)   you need to make sure that wherever the `kmos` shell client is is in your `$PATH` variable. When you installed kmos (`pip install --user --upgrade kmos`) it should tell where it went. That directory needs to show up when you run `echo $PATH`. Most likely something like `~/.local/bin`. If it doesn't show up you may want to put `export PATH=${PATH}:~/.local/bin` into your `~/.bashrc` or the corresponding syntax in your `echo $SHELL` configuration file.

The other location is where the python module gets copied to. When you do the pip installation it should print this out as well. Most likely something like `~/.local/lib/pythonXY/site-packages`. When you run `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` it should include given directory. You can automatically add this directory again using your `echo ${SHELL}` configuration file like `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:~/.local/lib/pythonXY/site-packages`.

If you can already import kmos from python then `python -c "import kmos; print(kmos.__file__)"` will tell you where it found it.